# gulp-watch works only on initial run

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

**What I do?**

1. Run `gulp` (SCSS files are being processed, I get a CSS file)
2. I change any SCSS file again

**Expected:**

- CSS file from 1. is updated with the changes from 2.

**What happens?**

- CSS file from 1. isn't changed

**Command line output:**

```
$ gulp
[09:24:28] Using gulpfile c:\Users\User\_dev\github\project\gulpfile.js
[09:24:28] Starting 'sass'...
[09:24:28] Finished 'sass' after 98 ms
[09:24:28] Starting 'default'...
[09:24:28] Finished 'default' after 7.31 μs
[09:24:35] sass-watch saw _base.scss was changed
[09:25:39] sass-watch saw _base.scss was changed
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    watch({ glob: 'css/**/*.{scss,sass}', name: 'sass-watch'})
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

Notes:

- [Issue on GitHub (gulp)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/572)
- [Issue on GitHub (gulp-watch)](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/51)
- [gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/kleinfreund/4a5717e187e4e7a2a730/d52404f6fd650d51c23bc475288fc5aa948ab319) on GitHub Gist)
- OS: Win7
- node: 0.10.29
- npm: 1.4.14

The way the source files are piped in is not important. The result stays the same when using `gulp.src()`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your sass task is correctly written.

Try something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('PATH-TO-SASS-FILES/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Comment: Please read about the `gulp-watch` plugin and its syntax [here](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch). I tried using `.src()`, I tried using only `.sass()`. The issue is exactly the same when using the plugin `gulp-watch` or when using the built in `gulp.watch`.